# SAS Macro with Return value with more text afterwards

Tags: macros, sas, return, return-value, sas-macro

Is it possible to return a value from a SAS macro, and continue the current SAS line after returning the value?

e.g.
Desired output to SAS (without quotes):

"set test.hello_2018_2020_2028;"

I've tried the following:

```
%MACRO returnFunc(passVar);
    %local testReturn;
    %let testReturn = %eval(&passVar +1);
    &testReturn
    %return;
%MEND returnFunc;

%MACRO test;
    %local var1;
    %local varPassed;
    %local anotherVar;

    %let var1 = 2018;
    %let varPassed = 2019;
    %let anotherVar = 2028;

    set test.hello_&var1._%returnFunc(&varPassed)_&anotherVar;
%MEND test;
```

However I get errors like the following:

- File test.hello_2018_2020.DATA does not exist
- File WORK._2028 Does not exist

So the macro returns the value fine, however it starts trying to make another set statement instead of adding _&anotherVar to the set statement

Comment: I think you need an `&` in front of `testReturn` in the first macro. Also, try removing the period after `%returnFunc(&varPassed).`.

Comment: You can, but PROC FCMP is not a bad option for that as well.

Comment: I'm thinking %UNQUOTE is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes %UNQUOTE and remove the . after the macro call.

```
111  %MACRO returnFunc(passVar);
112      %local testReturn;
113      %let testReturn = %eval(&passVar +1);
114      &testReturn
115      %return;
116  %MEND returnFunc;
117
118  %MACRO test;
119      %local var1;
120      %local varPassed;
121      %local anotherVar;
122
123      %let var1 = 2018;
124      %let varPassed = 2019;
125      %let anotherVar = 2028;
126
127      set %unquote(test.hello_&var1._%returnFunc(&varPassed)_&anotherVar);
128  %MEND test;
129  options mprint=1;
130  data _null_;
131     %test;
MPRINT(TEST):   set
MPRINT(TEST):   test.hello_2018_2020_2028;
ERROR: Libref TEST is not assigned.
132     run;
```